# Duplicate parameters in Angular parants

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to add multiple parameters with the same name to a request URL. I'm using Angular's $http.

The URL should look like this: http://myBaseUrl?name1=value1&name1=value2...

```
this._router.navigate([], {
         queryParams: {
            newOrdNum:element.nativeElement.value
         },    queryParamsHandling: 'merge', 
});
```

but params is replace The URL is  http://myBaseUrl?name1=value2

Comment: why don't you pass same key value comma separated like `name1=value1,value2,value3`?

Comment: What is the output from `element.nativeElement.value`? `value1` and `value2` comma separated?

Comment: I did it like this, send in a variable, separated by commas